# PowerShell Get-ADGroupMember for distribution group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get the user list from distribution group using the below power shell command, but it throws an error message. tested this with Security Group and it works fine. Not sure if I have to mention anything specific for Distribution Group?

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity GroupName
```

> ```
> get-adgroupmember : An operations error occurred
> At line:5 char:1
> + get-adgroupmember -Identity GroupName
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (GroupName:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8224,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
> ```

Comment: I tested and I am able to return distribution group members with that cmdlet.
Are you sure you are passing in a value?

`NotSpecified: (GroupName:ADGroup)`

Comment: Yes, I'm passing the actual distribution group name, I just masked it here.

Comment: Test it with security group from your ad then look for your distro in exchange or where else it might be. Only AD based groups can be searched by the cmdlet

Comment: actually Get-ADGroup -Identity <<GroupName>> works fine for the same distribution Group. But Get-ADGroupMember is not working.

Comment: Are there any members in this group belonging to a different domain? `Get-ADGroupMember` cannot actually handle this. Try `(Get-ADGroup $groupname -properties member).member` to check

Comment: thanks! you are right, it has different domain and (Get-ADGroup $groupname -properties member).member worked. one more thing ask, is there a way to do recursive lookup and   how to get the email alias from .member. thanks again!